# (H-LP RH HI) On fuse panel. What is it used for?

Tags: camry, o2-sensor, fuse-panel

What does "H-LP RH HI" mean for a 20A fuse?

Where can I find the o2 sensor fuse? Toyota Camry 6 cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

H-LP RH HI is head lamp (headlight), right-hand (right side), high beam.

The oxygen sensor does not have a separate fuse. Look for a fuse indexed with the word EFI, which supplies many things including the oxygen sensor.

Comment: Thank you very much unwere very helpful